# android z-index issue

Tags: android, css

We have a webapp that we're trying to use with android and have run into a z-index issue.  We are using asp.net with a lot of custom javascript.  Everything works great in chrome, firefox, ie7, 8, 9 and kindle but android does not seem to respect a particular z-index on a div that we create dynamically.

So we have a modal dialog that has a grid control and when you select a grid item, it shows a menu with buttons.  These are all divs.  So the modal dialog div has a higher z-index than all other page divs and the menu div has the highest z-index.  On android, the menu div appears under the modal dialog div.

I've tried numerous things to get this menu to show on top of the modal dialog such as asking for the z-index after the menu is displayed (which is correct, the highest z-index of all absolute items), assigning a new higher z-index after it is displayed, moving the order of the divs around, etc and nothing seems to put it on top of the dialog as it does in all other browsers.

Comment: See my answer & please rate it if it has helped. Cheers!!